# OpenCV 3.0 cvAbsDiff() - No matching function for call to 'cvAbsDiff'

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, opencv3.0

So i see - No matching function for call to 'cvAbsDiff' message, i don't know why but i can't compile this code.

Xcode advise convert cv::Mat to CvArr. But this is crazy way.

```
cv::Mat firstFrame;

- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image;
{

    cv::Mat diffFrame=image.clone();

    cv::Mat currentFrame=image.clone();

    cvtColor(image, currentFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    if (countNonZero(firstFrame) < 1){firstFrame=currentFrame;}
    else
    {

        cvAbsDiff(firstFrame,currentFrame,image);
//        image=diffFrame;



    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cvAbsDiff` function is designed to work with the older C api, which uses `IplImage` rather than `cv::Mat` to store images. Instead when working with C++ you can just use the `cv::absdiff` function:

```
cv::absdiff(firstFrame, currentFrame, image);
```

For future reference, if you need to convert a `cv::Mat` to an `IplImage`, you can do so by assiging it, but generally you should try and avoid mixing the two API styles.

```
IplImage ipl = myMatImage;.
```

If you look at the [OpenCV array operations documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) you will see that the various functions are listed with both their C and C++ variants.